# How to scrape company ratings from an Indeed job site in R

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I have never worked with HTML or CSS but I know R, so I have looked at several scraping methods online and here in Stack to do it in R. I am keep having issues extracting company ratings from the job listing page. I get `character(0)` where as in the example url the company has `4.0` rating.

Here is my attempt:

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)

#example URL
url<- "https://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=a25a91736b1f7042&tk=1e3q54n49heai800&from=serp&vjs=3&advn=8876452989351355&adid=95236293&sjdu=TDSJNe66qIM3gcXFOG94m--bPylNW2vvO3WAHEKN7JhCAD1FQ-2FXD1gQyElsLNkg6gfXO2CD3rQYOYjO9iXITyFdYOp8tCECkHuDmf3Og8qdMmciGFIv2ahigETjLmuY8uXdLjnQTg4__yOXqHJkA"

page<- read_html(url)


page%>%
   rvest::html_nodes("span")  %>%
   rvest::html_nodes(xpath = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "ratingsContent", " " ))]')%>%
   rvest::html_text()

#Output is 
#character(0)
#Where as it should have been 4.0!
```

Could anyone please show me how to get it, and if the company is missing the rating how do I return `NA`? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the wrong xpath. From looking at the source document, the value you are looking for is contained in the `content` attribute of `meta` tags which have the `itemprop` attribute `"ratingValue"`.

The following is a working reproducible example using your question's url:

```r
read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//meta[contains(@itemprop, 'ratingValue')]") %>%
  html_attr("content") %>%
  unique()
#> [1] "4.0"
```

Comment: I used an extension on chrome to get the xpath, other were pretty accurate, don't know how this went wrong. But thank you Allan. Really appreciate your answer!